# Presenting and passing data to a modal view controller without using prepare(for:sender:) method

Tags: swift, ios, cocoa-touch

I am using a toolbar button to present a modal view controller (in which I let the user export data as a PDF file). The main section of my app is a `UITableViewController` subclass embedded in a `UINavigationController`.

Here is a schematic of my layout.

[image: Schematic of my storyboard layout]

The modal itself is embedded in a `UINavigationController` as I need it to have a bottom toolbar. It also has a transparent background and is presented using `.overCurrentContext`, so the main screen of the user's data blurs underneath.

I found that to get it to *float* over everything else (including the navigation bar etc), I had to present it from the `UINavigationController` (otherwise the main navigation bar and toolbar appeared on top of it).
The problem with this is that the `UITableViewController` method `prepare(for:sender:)` is not called.

I call the segue to the modal view controller like this (from the `UITableViewController` subclass):

```
// User taps EXPORT button
@objc func exportButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.navigationController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showExport", sender: nil)
}
```

In order to transfer the array of user data to the modal view controller, I have called the following code in the *modal* view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Get data from array in main table view controller
    let masterNav = navigationController?.presentingViewController as! UINavigationController
    let myTableVC = masterNav.topViewController as! MyTableViewController
    self.userData = myTableVC.userData // This is of type: [MyObject]
}
```

The data is then rendered to a PDF (using HTML templating) in the modal view controller's `viewWillAppear()` method. This works as expected.

However, I have some concerns about doing it this way:

1. Is it guaranteed that `viewDidLoad()` will finish before `viewWillAppear()` is called? Will an even a larger data set be available for rendering as PDF in `viewWillAppear()`?
2. Is it acceptable to present modally from the `UINavigationController`?
3. Should I be subclassing the main `UINavigationController` and using its `prepare(for:sender:)` method (if this is even an option)?
4. In the `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` method, does the sender argument make any difference?
5. Is it preferable to use `present()` rather than a segue?

I would of course be grateful for any other advice or refinements to the code. It seems to work as expected but I just want to make sure I following best practice as far as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it guaranteed that viewDidLoad() will finish before viewWillAppear() is called? Will an even a larger data set be available for rendering as PDF in viewWillAppear()?

Yes. It needs to be loaded before it will appear.

> Is it acceptable to present modally from the UINavigationController?

I think it is.

> Should I be subclassing the main UINavigationController and using its prepare(for:sender:) method (if this is even an option)?

It sounds a bit complicated. `prepare(for:sender:)` is not a very clean way to do transfer data to begin with and only useful when you use segues in a regular way. Why don't you create the `ModalViewController` in code, set the value and then push it through code instead?

> In the performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:) method, does the sender argument make any difference?

I used it in rare occasions to understand where the push was coming from.

> Is it preferable to use present() rather than a segue?

I think in your case yes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I like these ideas - I’m going to try making the view controller in code.

Comment: That's not necessary. You can instantiate it from a storyboard or XIB if you want and then push it all through code.

Comment: Ah yes I see what you mean. That sounds easier as I already have my Storyboard made!